# AlamoFire GET api request not working as expected

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to get learn how to use AlamoFire and I am having trouble.

My method so far is as follows:

```
func siteInfo()->String?{
    var info:NSDictionary!
    var str:String!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, MY_API_END_POINT).responseJSON {(request, response, JSON, error) in
        info = JSON as NSDictionary
        str = info["access_key"] as String
        //return str
    }
    return str
}
```

This returns nil which is a problem. From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141829/swift-closure-with-alamofire), this is because the request can take a while so the closure doesn't execute till after the return. The suggested solution of moving the return into the closure does not work for me and the compiler just yells (adding `->String` after `(request,response,JSON,error)` which gives "'String' is not a subtype of void"). Same goes for the other solution provided.

Any ideas? Even some source code that is not related to this problem, that uses AlamoFire, would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to figure out how to return data with alamofire without a completion handler?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to handle this is to pass a closure (I usually call it a `completionHandler`) to your `siteInfo` function and call that inside `Alamofire.request`'s closure:

```
func siteInfo(completionHandler: (String?, NSError?) -> ()) -> () {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, MY_API_END_POINT).responseJSON {
        (request, response, JSON, error) in

        let info = JSON as? NSDictionary // info will be nil if it's not an NSDictionary
        let str = info?["access_key"] as? String // str will be nil if info is nil or the value for "access_key" is not a String

        completionHandler(str, error)
    }
}
```

Then call it like this (don't forget error handling):

```
siteInfo { (str, error) in
    if str != nil {
        // Use str value
    } else {
        // Handle error / nil value
    }
}
```

---

### In the comments you asked:

> So how would you save the info you collect from the get request if you
>   can only do stuff inside the closure and not effect objects outside of
>   the closure? Also, how to keep track to know when the request has
>   finished?

You can save the result of the get request to an instance variable in your class from inside the closure; there's nothing about the closure stopping you from doing that. What you do from there really depends on, well, what you want to do with that data.

### How about an example?

Since it looks like you're getting an access key form that get request, maybe you need that for future requests made in other functions.

In that case, you can do something like this:

***Note:** Asynchronous programming is a huge topic; way too much to cover here. This is just one example of how you might handle the data you get back from your asynchronous request.*

```
public class Site {
    private var _accessKey: String?

    private func getAccessKey(completionHandler: (String?, NSError?) -> ()) -> () {

        // If we already have an access key, call the completion handler with it immediately
        if let accessKey = self._accessKey {
            completionHandler(accessKey, nil)
        } else { // Otherwise request one
            Alamofire.request(.GET, MY_API_END_POINT).responseJSON {
                (request, response, JSON, error) in

                let info = JSON as? NSDictionary // info will be nil if it's not an NSDictionary
                let accessKey = info?["access_key"] as? String // accessKey will be nil if info is nil or the value for "access_key" is not a String

                self._accessKey = accessKey
                completionHandler(accessKey, error)
            }
        }
    }

    public func somethingNeedingAccessKey() {
        getAccessKey { (accessKey, error) in
            if accessKey != nil {
                // Use accessKey however you'd like here
                println(accessKey)
            } else {
                // Handle error / nil accessKey here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that setup, calling `somethingNeedingAccessKey()` the first time will trigger a request to get the access key. Any calls to `somethingNeedingAccessKey()` after that will use the value already stored in `self._accessKey`. If you do the rest of `somethingNeedingAccessKey`'s work inside the closure being passed to `getAccessKey`, you can be sure that your `accessKey` will always be valid. If you need another function that needs `accessKey`, just write it the same way `somethingNeedingAccessKey` is written.

```
public func somethingElse() {
    getAccessKey { (accessKey, error) in
        if accessKey != nil {
            // Do something else with accessKey
        } else {
            // Handle nil accessKey / error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you end up with the same problem here? e.g.

        `var stuff:String! 
siteInfo{ str in stuff = str }
        println(stuff)`

Which prints nil

Comment: Yes, but then you're not really working with asynchronous functions correctly.  You need to do everything that has to be done after your siteInfo function (like that println) inside the closure.

Comment: So how would you save the info you collect from the get request if you can only do stuff inside the closure and not effect objects outside of the closure? Sorry for the noobish questions but I am a bit confused.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. It may not be exactly what you're trying to do, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: This seems like it could get complicated fast when designing an app and api. Do you know of any books that you would recommend on this topic (asynchronous and synchronous requests)? Thanks for the response!

Comment: It definitely can (and does) get complicated. I would suggest reading Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1). It is heavily focused on GCD and `NSOperationQueue`s though, so you might also want to search around for some more general reading (I don't have anything offhand, sorry).

Comment: just to be sure: `if accessKey != nil` is on the main thread again, right? So it is safe to set variables on `self` object that might be used by the UI directly later?