# swift alamofire return value is empty

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hi i have the following method:

```
    func getAlamoPlayers() ->[Player]{


    //Get TeamID
    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var TeamId:String = prefs.stringForKey("TEAMID")!

    //create parameters for POST
    let parameters =
    ["IdTeam": TeamId]

    var result: NSArray?

    //Request
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "XXXXXX.php", parameters: parameters)

        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in

            result = (json as NSArray)
            // Make models from Json data
            for (var i = 0; i < result?.count; i++) {
                let dic: NSDictionary = result![i] as NSDictionary
                //Create a team object
                var p:Player = Player()

                //Assign the values of each key value pair to the team object
                p.PlayerID    = dic["IdPlayer"] as String
                p.PlayerName  = dic["name"] as String
                p.PlayerFkToTeam = dic["teams_IdTeam"] as String

                //Add the team to the player array
                self.players.append(p)

            }

    }

    return self.players
}
```

So when i call this method in another class the players array is empty! How can I handle the asynchronous request of alamofire? I think the method returns the player object before the request is finished, or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a question that asks basically the same thing you are.

[AlamoFire GET api request not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected)

So basically what is happening is that your post request is being called in a background queue. So think of it as calling your post then continuing on to the next line. So since it is in a background thread it doesn't set the variable till after your function returns.

You could use a completion handler as explained in detail in the link I provided. Another solution would be to use NSNotificationCenter. Set up an observer and then post a notification inside your POST request.

So for example:
First declare your notification name at the top of the class where you will have your post response function as so. So that other classes can access it

`let YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME = "NOTIFICATION NAME"
class YOUR_CLASS{`

then inside the class write the code you want to execute once the POST is done.

`func YOUR_FUNCTION{
  ...
}`

Then before you execute your POST request you want to add an observer.

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "YOUR_FUNCTION", name: YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME, object: nil)`

Then post your notification inside your POST request.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "XXXXXX.php", parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
         ...<your code>...
   self.players.append(p)
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME, object: self)
}
```

Comment: ok, i will test this tomorrow. Does it matter if the function with the alamofire request is in a seperate class?

Comment: That is why you have the `YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME` so that the NSNotificationCenter knows what notification you are talking about. So you want `YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME`, the `.addObserver`, and `YOUR_FUNCTION` in the same class. The `.postNotificationName` can be called else where. Once you post your notification it will call the function with the name you put in the selector.

Comment: I have implemented your solution from the link above. Thanks, now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

so i've build it in the following way:

Modell Class with all requests:

```
let finishedPlayers = "finishedPlayers"
class StrafenkatalogModel: NSObject {
.
.
func getAlamoPlayers()-> [Player] {

    //Get TeamID
    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var TeamId:String = prefs.stringForKey("TEAMID")!

    //create parameters for POST
    let parameters =
    ["IdTeam": TeamId]

    var result: NSArray?

    //Observer
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "returnPlayers", name: finishedPlayers, object: nil)
    //Request
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://smodeonline.com/XXXXXXX.php", parameters: parameters)

        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in



            result = (json as NSArray)
            // Make models from Json data
            for (var i = 0; i < result?.count; i++) {
                let dic: NSDictionary = result![i] as NSDictionary
                //Create a team object
                var p:Player = Player()

                //Assign the values of each key value pair to the team object
                p.PlayerID    = dic["IdPlayer"] as String
                p.PlayerName  = dic["name"] as String
                p.PlayerFkToTeam = dic["teams_IdTeam"] as String

                //Add the team to the teams array
                self.players.append(p)


            }

    }
    return players  
}


func returnPlayers() ->[Player]{
    return self.players
}
```

Then i want to call it in the TableViewController class (Class2):

```
class AddPlayersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let model:StrafenkatalogModel = StrafenkatalogModel()
var players:[Player] = [Player]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Get Player objects from the model
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("finishedPlayers", object: self)
    self.players = self.model.returnPlayers()
    .
    .
    }
```

But the players object is empty. Does you know why? Did i something wrong?