# How do I get data out of a firebase snapshot in Swift using a function in a struct?

Tags: swift, struct, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm getting data from Cloud Firestore to populate a ListView. I've managed to get the data into an array, but when I return the array, it shows up empty.

//Edit

I've implemented a completion handler, works perfectly for 'Test Code', but when called in 'func industryPosts' and passed into 'myArray', it returns nil. While 'Test Code' returns data. I'm new to completion handlers, and Swift in general. Kindly let me know what I'm missing. Thanks.

//Edit
I was not able to return the values, but calling industryPosts where I needed to use it worked!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class IndustryData {

    var _snapshotArray : Array<Any>?

    func getSnapshotArray(collectionRef: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Array<Any>?, NSError?) -> ()){

        if let snapArray = self._snapshotArray {
            completionHandler(snapArray, nil)
        } else {

            var snapArray : Array<Any> = []

            db.collection(collectionRef).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                    print("Error - > \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let item = Industry(avatar: document.get("avatar") as! String, name:document.documentID, tags: document.get("tags") as! String)
                    snapArray.append(item)
                }
                self._snapshotArray = snapArray
                completionHandler(snapArray, error as NSError?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then calling the below function where needed

```
func getposts()-> [Industry] {
        let data = IndustryData()
        data.getSnapshotArray(collectionRef: "industry") { (snapshotArray, error) in
            if snapshotArray != nil {
                self.myArray = snapshotArray!
            }
        }
        return myArray as! [Industry]
    }
```

myArray returned Industry Array!

Comment: You have to use a completion block to return te data, simply using return will result returning the array without getting the data from firestore. I can add an example if you wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift alamofire return value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377824/swift-alamofire-return-value-is-empty)

Comment: Thanks @AchidF, I would appreciate a sample code.

Comment: @Joakim, I followed the code on the other question, and it works as expected with a sample code. I'm updating the question to reflect what I've implemented so far. I'm new to all this, kindly bear with me,...