# Array keeps returning nil even when values are stored Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, firebase

Hi I am new to Swift and Firebase here and I am trying to append the objects I get into the array I have created. But when I return the array, it returns nil even when I print the array it shows the values are stored inside.I tried to assign it to another array but it still returns nil. Please help me as I am currently a newbie to Swift and Firebase and need some guidance. Thanks in advance.

```
func retrieveData() -> Array<AnyObject>{
    var ref = Firebase(url: "my_firebase_url")
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("datetime").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        if let i = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            for item in i {
                if let value = item.value as? NSDictionary {


                    self.adArray.append(value)
                    println(self.adArray[0])
                    println(self.adArray.count)
                 self.codeNum = value["code"] as! String
                 self.datetime = value["datetime"] as! String
                 self.nameEvent = value["name"] as! String
                    println("code is \(self.codeNum) and name is \(self.nameEvent) at \(self.datetime)")
                }
            }
        }
    })
    println(adArray.count)
  return adArray }
```

Comment: Why don't you declare a local array inside `receiveData` and append to it?

Comment: @flashadvanced yes i tried that as well but the result is still the same.

Comment: if you want to return "`adArray`", declare a local `adArray` variable (within the function) and work with that.  You're doing all of your operations on your `self.adArray` (which is a class property) and you're not returning `self.adArray`.

Comment: I assume that the query is *asynchronously*, i.e. the function returns *before* the query is finished and fills the array? – Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected which is (probably) the same problem.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yeah I have tried that as well but when I try to use the object it still is empty.