# Alamofire returning of value outside scope - how that code works?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

Sorry if my question is silly, but im totally new in programming and swift

I needed to return a value from alamofire, i crawled stackoverflow a little and got the code that working.

here it is

```
 func getQuests(completionHandler: (NSDictionary) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { _, _, json, _ in
            completionHandler(json as! NSDictionary)
        }
    }

    var myQuests: NSDictionary?

    getQuests() { quests in myQuests = quests
        println(myQuests!)
    }
```

the question is whats role of "quests in myQuests = quests". what is it ? How is it connected to getQuests and alamofire ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AlamoFire GET api request not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Your question title is different but this post contains your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trailing closure you are passing as the completion handler.

```
{ quests in myQuests = quests
        println(myQuests!)
}
```

quests is the NSDictionary that is being passed into the closure.
[Swift closure documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)