# Swift JSON result compare to string

Tags: json, string, swift, alamofire

I'm developing iOS app that needs to request JSON for username/password validation. I found and used Alamofire framework. If I debug this app, the print show 1, but the the condition is evaluated as true (var ok is never true).

```
static func userPasswordCheck(username:String,password: String) -> Bool{
    var ok = false
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://is.xxxxxxx.com/api/login?username="+username+"&password="+password)
        .responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print(String(JSON["responseCode"]!!.description))
                    if(String(JSON["responseCode"]!!.description)=="1"){
                        ok =  true
                    }
                }
    }
    return ok
}
```

Comment: [Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handling)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [AlamoFire GET api request not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25901460/2006429)