# alamofire get request return null value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have one problem. I am reuesting with alamofire an it return value. In alamofire i convert returned json to my custom class, its work goog. But when i am using this converted class out of alamofire body it returned nil value.
I put breakpoint in alamofire where i converted json value and appent to my class, it has value and it put it to my class.But out of body it equal nil. Why?

```
func getZakazDetail(orderID:Int,tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView){

    if flag{
        let zD=ZakazDetailTableViewController()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "myUrl")
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let product = JSON(value)
                    if product != nil{
                        for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {
                            let p=ZakazDetail(id: subJson["id"].int!, tovar: subJson["tovar"].string!, count: subJson["count"].int!, orderid: subJson["orderid"].int!, cena: subJson["cena"].int!)
                            self.zakazDetail.append(p)
                            zD.detail.append(p)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because alamofire loads the data asynchronously and before you append anything in zD.detail.append(p). 
Add a completion handler for the program to wait till the loading is complete.

```
//here you call authenticateUser with a closure that prints responseObject
API().authenticateUser{ (responseObject, error) in
    println(responseObject)
}
```

Then:

```
//authenticateUser receives your closure as a parameter
func authenticateUser(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    //it passes your closure to makeAuthenticateUserCall
    makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler)
}

//makeAuthenticateUserCall receives your closure
func makeAuthenticateUserCall(completionHandler: (responseObject: String?, 
error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, loginUrlString)
        .authenticate(user: "a", password: "b")
        //here you pass a new closure to the responseString method
        .responseString { request, response, responseString, responseError in
            //in this closure body you call your completionHandler closure with the 
            //parameters passed by responseString and your code gets executed 
            //(that in your case just prints the responseObject)
            completionHandler(responseObject: responseString as String!, error: responseError)
    }
}
```

For more information read the documentation: [Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: but there are it already download json  let product = JSON(value)

Comment: Yeah well you should tell the code to not append anything till alamofire loads the data, Then once it is done, you can append it and reload the data.

Comment: like this:
func getZakazDetail(orderID:Int,tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView,completion : (JSON) -> ())                                                                                 let product = JSON(value)
completion(product)

Comment: Woah woah that's not how you add a completion handler. Check out my answer. It should help you. I've edited it.

Comment: func getZakazDetailRequest(completionHandler: (responseObject:JSON) -> ()) {
        makeGetZakazDetail(completionHandler)
    }

Comment: func makeGetZakazDetail(completionHandler: (responseObject:JSON) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "")
            .responseJSON {response in
                //in this closure body you call your completionHandler closure with the
                //parameters passed by responseString and your code gets executed
                //(that in your case just prints the responseObject)
                completionHandler(responseObject: JSON(response.result.value!))
        }
    }

Comment: func getZakazDetail(orderID:Int,tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView){
        getZakazDetailRequest{(responseObject) in
            if responseObject != nil{
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in responseObject {
                    let p=ZakazDetail(id: subJson["id"].int!, tovar: subJson["tovar"].string!, count: subJson["count"].int!, orderid: subJson["orderid"].int!, cena: subJson["cena"].int!)
                    self.zakazDetail.append(p)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: No it's not proper. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected) .

Comment: Anytime. :) And yes it is proper, sorry I couldn't read the code properly, Happy coding.