# Swift: Return Type JSON from function

Tags: json, swift

so I've got a function that needs to return a JSON object that is received from an API endpoint. For some reason, this function always returns nil, even though when I print the response.result.value, it contains the API response perfectly, and enters the if statement to assign to returnJSON. Would appreciate any input!

```
func storeContact(name: String, number: String, apiToken: String) -> AnyObject? {

var returnJSON: AnyObject?

let contact = ["api_token" : apiToken, "name" : name, "number": number]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://sample.app/api/v1/contact", parameters: contact, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

    if let value = response.result.value {

        returnJSON = value

    }
}

return returnJSON

}
```

Comment: Why don't you parse the JSON into dictionary and return dictionary? Also you are returning `returnJSON` before the results are received from your POST request therefore it is nil. Use blocks.

Comment: See how to use [Swift Closures with Alamofire for Network requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141829/swift-closure-with-alamofire)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alamofire use asynchronous calls, because internet fetches always need some times. Completion block of `Alamofire.request` always invoked *after* `storeContact` return it value. Its common to use closures in this situation:

```
func storeContact(name: String, number: String, apiToken: String, completeonClosure: (AnyObject?) -> ()) {
    let contact = ["api_token" : apiToken, "name" : name, "number": number]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://sample.app/api/v1/contact", parameters: contact, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        response in
        completeonClosure(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
storeContact("name", number: "number", apiToken: "apiToken") {
    returnJSON in
    print(returnJSON)
}
```