# How do I update this variable with data

Tags: swift

New programmer here! I'm working with a network request and below is a snippet of my code. After I complete the network request I want to store a value from the request into a variable. However, when the variable is called outside of the if let statement it is NOT updated. Essentially, the print statement inside the if let statement prints the value I'm looking for, but the print statement outside of the `if let` statement prints the default value I set for that variable. The variable is global. I need to use that updated variable elsewhere in my code, any ideas?

```
        if let data = data {
            self.nameLabel.text = data.name
            person = data.name
            print(person)
        }
        print(person)
```

Comment: You don't show enough context. Most likely your `print` is outside of the async completion block.

Comment: Also try to replace one print something like print("\(person) : person from  inside"),  makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you didn't showed complete code so I am guessing you need main queue to update your `UILabel` first as shown in below code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.nameLabel.text = data.name
}
```

next thing is if you want to access the value somewhere else once your request completes and `UILabel` updated then you can get the value from it this way:

```
let value = self.nameLabel.text!
```

And if you want to access the value once request complete then you can use closure and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141829/swift-closure-with-alamofire) you can check example of it.